# Repairing data sources using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, layers, table-of-contents

I work with MXD file that contain 50 layers (all layers located in different folders), some of them have broken Data source:

[image]

The problem is that anytime i try to repair all the layers data source simultaneously, with right click on the layer name in the table of content:

[image]

all the layers get the same path- and that absolutely wrong and mistake. How can i change each layer to her right path simultaneously using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop?

Answer (score 4):

From ArcCatalog, right-click on the .mxd file and select "Set Data Sources".

Using this approach you can see all of the data sources used in the mxd by feature layer. You can edit the sources one at a time, or highlight several layers and use right-click "replace" to update the entire group.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to end up doing it manually for each one. In the layer Properties go to the Source tab. You can set the correct file path for each file by pressing the Set Data Source button.